# Django form submit url not working

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm new to Django and cannot figure out why my form is not working. It seems that after form submit even though the url is being changed to `/82nsj/update` it is still going to the `index` method in the view.

**Views**

```
from business.models import Business, Token
from django.shortcuts import render
from business.forms import BusinessForm

def index(request, token):
    try:
        business = Business.objects.get(token__token=token)
    except Token.DoesNotExist:
        business = None
    except Business.DoesNotExist:
        business = None

    form = BusinessForm(instance=business)
    return render(request, 'business/index.html', {'form': form})

def update(request, token):
    try:
        business = Business.objects.get(token__token=token)
    except Token.DoesNotExist:
        business = None
    except Business.DoesNotExist:
        business = None

    form = BusinessForm(request.POST, instance=business)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return render(request, 'business/index.html', {'form': form})
```

**Urls**

```
url(r'^$', 'business.views.index', name='home'),
url(r'^business/(?P<token>\w+)/', 'business.views.index', name='business'),
url(r'^business/(?P<token>\w+)/update/', 'business.views.update', name='business_update'),
```

**Forms**

```
self.helper = FormHelper(self)
self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
self.helper.form_action = 'update/'
self.helper.form_method = 'post'
self.helper.layout = Layout(
    HTML("<p class='alert-info alert'>Please confirm your business contact information is updated and correct.</p>"),
    Div(
        'my',
                'fields',
        FormActions(
            Submit('save_changes', 'Save changes', css_class="btn-primary"),
        ),
        css_class='row-fluid'
    )
)
```

I know this isn't working because I have breakpoints setup in my `index` and in my `update` and after I press the submit button only the `index` breakpoint is being reached.

What am I doing wrong that is preventing the `update` method from running on form submit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably an issue with your `url(...` regex.

Django will go to the first URL that matches so if you have this

```
url(r'^business/(?P<token>\w+)/', 'business.views.index', name='business'),
url(r'^business/(?P<token>\w+)/update/', 'business.views.update', name='business_update'),
```

going to `/business/<token>/anything_goes_here` will always go to `business.views.index`.

To stop this, include a `$` for `end of expression`.

```
url(r'^business/(?P<token>\w+)/$', 'business.views.index', name='business'),
```

Now your `/business/<token>/update/` wont match the first URL and will then match `business.views.update`.